# Can a UK citizen work remotely in the UK for a Spanish company?

Tags: taxes, working-abroad, brexit

I am looking for a job in Spain working remotely from the UK. Do you know how this works? Will I need to pay income tax both in the UK and Spain? This will change after the Brexit? Thank you in advance!